# Is there a way to tell the charging speed (or wattage or estimated finish time) on an iPhone/Watch

Tags: iphone, charging, apple-watch

I've bought so many Apple chargers and cables over the years that I have no idea which ones go to which device. Apple doesn't label any of these, which further confuses things.  Even if I threw out all the third party chargers and cables (if I could tell the difference), I have chargers and cables from iPhone 5 through 13, and Apple Watch Series 2 through 8, so I'm unsure which chargers and cables support which wattages/charging speeds.  I recently purchased a 20W PIQ 3.0 charger and fast-charge USB-C to Apple Watch charging cable, but in 20 minutes it only charged from 12% to 20%, whereas the charger that (I think) came with the watch charges at the advertised speeds.  Is there some way to determine how fast the charging will go without doing a full discharge/charge cycle on every combination of charger/cable?  Obviously the phone/watch knows how much power is being transferred.  While charging, there should be something that shows this or an ETA on-screen, but even an app would be better than not being able to determine this without waiting for a significant charge or period of time.  Is there some app that does this or some other way to tell?